# Configure Spark MLlib in Eclipse Scala IDE

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am facing problem, actually could not get any guideline how to configure spark MLlib in Eclipse Scala IDE. Can anyone help me out there providing me how to configure spark MLlib in Scala IDE?

In addition, can anybody tell me how to implement random forest (ensemble) in Spark (Scala) except Spark documentation? I am reading and working with documentation of Spark MLlib.

Comment: Are you using sbt or maven for your project?

Comment: @DavidMaust I'm using maven in my project.